# How to remove similar entries from array php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

So i have array like this and sometimes it has very similar entries:

```
Array
(
    [0] => greys anatomy
    [1] => element 3d
    [2] => interstellar
    [3] => monster ball
    [4] => scorpion
    [5] => taken 3
    [6] => the flash
    [7] => wild card
    [8] => big bang theory
    [9] => the big bang theory
    [10] => fredrik kempe vincero
    [11] => fredrik kempe vicero
)
```

I would like to remove similar entries that are longer ones. So for example in this array:  `[9] => the big bang theory` and `[10] => fredrik kempe vincero` entries should be removed. as they are similar to 8th and 11th entry, but longer.

EDIT:
So if anyone needs, I made working solution out of two answers below:

```
function check_similar($first, $second)
{
    similar_text($first, $second, $percent);
  if ($percent >= 80) { //needed percent value
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
   for ($j = $i; $j < count($array); $j++) {
      if ($j > $i && check_similar($array[$i],$array[$j]) == true) {
         $array[$j] = null;
      }
   }
}
// filter array to remove null values and reindex
$array = array_values(array_filter($array));
print_r($array);
```

Comment: And when is a element similar to another one ?

Comment: Id say similar would be more than 80% match

Comment: In that case "taken 2" and "taken 3" would be considered similar and one of them would get removed. But that's not what you want, is it?

Comment: just use array_unique() function and pass your array variable in to it will show the unique data

Comment: @Lalitpatadiya array_unique() will not remove "big bang theory" or "the big bang theory", since they are not _equal_ as per the function's understanding. Taken from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php): `Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2 i.e. when the string representation is the same, the first element will be used. ` The different flags wouldn't help either.

Comment: It wont be a huge problem if this wont work ideally. at least aprox matching would be awesome, as this function will be used for user search queries tagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String similarity is a very difficoult problem that cannot be solved easily. There are several complex approaches, but none can be effective as if it was made by a human being.

Take a look on php [soundhex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) and [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) which could be an easy solution for your particular case.

In any case, given a custom function that defines or not if a string is similar to another, to make your array unique you have to do something like:

```
// set to null all subsequent similar strings
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
   for ($j = $i; $j < count($array); $j++) {
      if ($j > $i && similar($array[$i],$array[$j])) {
         $array[$j] = null;
      }
   }
}
// filter array to remove null values
$array = array_filter($array);
```

Comment: Mixing this with web-nomads answer should resolve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function.

```
similar_text('the big bang theory','big bang theory', $percent);
echo $percent; // 88%
```

This is obviously more difficult than it seems, but can do this check while making this array.

See this [link](https://cambiatablog.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/algorithm-for-string-similarity-better-than-levenshtein-and-similar_text/) for an alternate implementation.